# Getting trackpacks/pingbacks for a post via wordpress?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

Is there a way for someone to query the wordpress API of a blog in order to get the pingbacks/trackbacks for a post?

E.g a blog is hosted on example.com. I want to query example.com's wordpress API to get a list of its posts, and for each post I want to query it, to get a list of the trackbacks.

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not asking how to get a virus off my wordpress blog. I'm asking how to do something via wordpress's API. API = Application Programming Interface = Programming related.

Comment: Well, if there is an API, can you please add some reference where that  interface is defined? That reference should lead you straight away to your programming btw.

Comment: If you don't know where the API is, you can't answer my question, this question is only for those familiar with the wordpress API. I suggest you move on to a different question, I'm not interested in this off topic derailment.

Comment: LOL dude, check my profile. I asked you so there is something useful for you to do. Because actually for my it's not clear *what* you ask about. And just seeing you accept the other anser, now please explain me where Wordpress API is in HTTP. So probably you didn't make yourself clear at all. Just giving pointers how to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find that information in the blog's feed, i.e. example.com/feed/ I'm unsure if the trackback would be public, you may have to view the Comments section of the WordPress blog.